# In wso2 how to write custom OAuth2 token validator

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In wso2 identity server how we can write custom Oauth2 token validator. As in wso2 identity server documentation there is no sample code available. And also how we can query oidc scope inside token validator for getting custom claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/extension-points-for-oauth/) what you are looking for is `OAuth2 Token Validator`

```
public class SO62997622 implements org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.validators.OAuth2TokenValidator {

    @Override
    public boolean validateAccessDelegation(OAuth2TokenValidationMessageContext oatvmc) throws IdentityOAuth2Exception {
        // Validate access
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateScope(OAuth2TokenValidationMessageContext oatvmc) throws IdentityOAuth2Exception {
        // Validate scopes
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateAccessToken(OAuth2TokenValidationMessageContext oatvmc) throws IdentityOAuth2Exception {
        // Validate the actual token
        return false;
    }

}
```

The documentation also has directions on how to enable your custom OAuth token validator and a Default implementation Class you can build upon. This is assuming Identity Server version 5.9 but should be pretty similar in previous versions.

For the second part of your question maybe [Claims Retriever](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/extension-points-for-oauth/#claims-retriever) is what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi thank you I have a question regarding token validator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63191333/in-wso2-identity-server-how-to-fetch-soap-haders-from-token-validator-api, can you please help